# Azure management API: How to change web app pricing tier?

Tags: c#, azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

I'm automating the creation of Azure web apps using the management SDK (i.e. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net) and it's not obvious how to change a web apps app service plan pricing tier using this SDK. Specifically I want to change the web apps I'm creating from 'Free' to 'Shared'.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `WebHostingPlanOperations.UpdateAsync()` ([WebHostingPlanOperations.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/ServiceManagement/WebSite/WebSiteManagement/Generated/WebHostingPlanOperations.cs)).

Notice that it takes a `WebHostingPlanUpdateParameters` object as a parameter (located in Models, [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/ServiceManagement/WebSite/WebSiteManagement/Generated/Models/WebHostingPlanUpdateParameters.cs)). Within that, you can set:

- `WorkerSize` (0, 1, or 2 for Small, Medium or Large)
- `SkuOptions` (which takes a `SkuOptions` enum, also in Models, [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/ServiceManagement/WebSite/WebSiteManagement/Generated/Models/SkuOptions.cs)).

`SkuOptions` values:

- Free = 0
- Shared = 1
- Basic = 2
- Standard = 3
- Premium = 4

Comment: Maybe worth noting for anyone else interested, implementing this was when I finally realised hosting plans and server farms are the same thing...

Answer (score -3):

You can change the pricing tier from the Portal

WebApps -> Select the Web App -> Scale -> Choose the desired Pricing Tier.

[image]

Comment: I need to do this via the SDK I referenced.